# San Francisco: Getting from Union Square to Hawk hill

Tags: public-transport, transportation, california, san-francisco

What are the possibilities to go from Union Square to Hawk Hill (the other side of the Golden Gate Bridge) excluding by foot/bicycle?

Factors I am interested in are the time it takes to get there, a rough price estimate and whether the suggested possibility would be possible during the night or early morning (<6.30 am)

Is there public transportation which doesn't require a lot of switches and loss of time?
Can I expect to take a taxi just anywhere?

Comment: Can you clarify this a little bit?  What is "efficient"?  Wny are relevant factors relevant and for what?  As far as Taxi's are concerned.  There are apps like Uber, Hailo, etc that you can check availability.

Comment: Let's not assume I have a smartphone or other intelligent-internet-connected device.

Answer (score 4):

As a simplest way to go you can check Google Public transportation option.

[Union Square to Hawk Hill](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Union+Square,+San+Francisco,+CA+94108&daddr=Hawk+Hill&hl=en&ll=37.808428,-122.453613&spn=0.105244,0.140762&sll=37.810883,-122.453119&sspn=0.10524,0.140762&geocode=FVqZQAId8zW0-Cm7QP3TjoCFgDG6tkyZtdlB_g%3BFcwrQQIdp86y-Cm1oqZc1oWFgDFKcvY5-IZZZg&oq=hawk+hi&t=h&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ltm&z=13&start=0) takes about an hour and a half using public transport.

As far as Taxis are concerned you can call for a pick up from many cab companies serving the city such as [Luxor Cab](http://www.luxorcab.com/) and some of their flat fare are published on their website.

Comment: Note that this public transit route drops you off at the north end of the Golden Gate bridge; it's a 2 mile uphill hike from there to the hill.  As far as I know, the only bus route into the Headlands is [Muni 76X](http://www.sfmta.com/getting-around/transit/routes-stops/76x-marin-headlands) which only runs weekends and will get you about halfway there.  I don't believe there's any transit up Conzelman Road.